# How to use tachyons-custom?

Tags: tachyons-css

I am using Tachyons CSS for my web app and I need to add a width css property of width 45% for medium screen. I did `npm install tachyons-custom` and I don't know what to do next. I couldn't find any tutorial online about adding a new tachyons property.

Can anyone give me a little guide? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to clone the actual `tachyons-css` repo and get [set up for local dev.](https://github.com/tachyons-css/tachyons-custom#local-setup)

Once you have the source files locally, you can add `.w-45 { width: 45%; }` (I presume) in the ["tachyons-custom/src/_widths.css" file](https://github.com/tachyons-css/tachyons-custom/blob/master/src/_widths.css#L57).

Don't forget to add the `.w-45-ns` and the rest if you want these, too.

Once you've done this, run `npm build`.

Now, `tachyons-custom/css/tachyons.css` will contain the new classes!